# Overleaf: Bibliography not working overleaf

Tags: bibliographies

I have to write my thesis for my graduation in latex and I'm having a problem with bibliography on overleaf.

```
\documentclass[epsfig,a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,outer=1.5cm,inner=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % per definizione layout
\usepackage{titlesec} % per formato custom dei titoli dei capitoli
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Package utilizzati
\usepackage{verbatim} % verbatim 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{pifont}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% supporto lettere accentate
%
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % per Windows;
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % per Linux (richiede il pacchetto unicode);
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} % per Mac.

\singlespacing

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}

% bibliografia in formato bibtex
    
    %inside here I have all my chapters imported with in \input{}

    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}
   
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{biblio}
    

\end{document}
```

and I have a **biblio.bib** file like this

```
@article{end-to-end,
  author = {Song Wang and Guanyu Li},
  title = {Overview of end-to-end speech recognition},
  journal = {J. Phys},
  year = {2019}
}

@misc{deepSpeech,
  title = {DeepSpeech’s documentation},
  howpublished = {https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/r0.9/DeepSpeech.html},
  note = {ultimo accesso 25/06/2021}
}

@book{tesi_filippo,
  author = {Filippo Tessaro},
  title = {Solutions for Simultaneous Speech Translation},
  publisher = {Department of Information Engineering and Computer Science, UniTN},
  year = {2020},
} 

@misc{verbatim,
  title = {Verbatim},
  howpublished = {https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbatim},
  note = {ultimo accesso 30/06/2021}
}

@book{windowing,
  author = {Daniel Jurafsky & James H. Martin},
  title = {Speech and Language Processing},
  publisher = {Prentice Hall PTR},
  year = {2020},
  edition = "3rd ed. draft"
 } 

@misc{mfcc,
  title = {Cepstrum and MFCC},
  howpublished = {https://wiki.aalto.fi/display/ITSP/Cepstrum+and+MFCC},
  note = {ultimo accesso 20/05/2021}
}

@book{mfcc-text,
  author = {K.S. Rao and Manjunath K.E},
  title = {Speech Recognition Using Articulatory and Excitation Source Features},
  publisher = {Springer Publishing Company},
  year = {2017},
 } 

@misc{wer-algo,
  title = {Word Error Rate Calculation},
  howpublished = {https://martin-thoma.com/word-error-rate-calculation/},
  note = {ultimo accesso 10/05/2021}
}

@misc{wer,
  title = {Word Error Rate},
  howpublished = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_error_rate},
  note = {ultimo accesso 10/05/2021}
}

@misc{lm-nn,
  title = {Language Modeling: Types and Importance in Artificial Intelligence},
  howpublished = {https://aiseed.co/language-modeling-types-and-importance-in-artificial-intelligence/},
  note = {ultimo accesso 14/06/2021}
}

@misc{intro_asr,
  title = {Riconoscimento vocale},
  howpublished = {https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riconoscimento_vocale},
  note = {ultimo accesso 24/06/2021}
}

@misc{lm-valutazione,
  title = {Modello linguistico con N-Grammi},
  howpublished = {https://enricogiannini.com/15/modello-linguistico-con-n-grammi/},
  note = {ultimo accesso 25/06/2021}
}

@unpublished{unita-base,
  Author = {Carovano Natalino},
  Title = {Speech To Text}
  Institution = {Università di Pisa},
  howpublished = {http://groups.di.unipi.it/~cappelli/seminari/carovano.pdf},
  Year = {2007},
}

@misc{wiki_viterbi,
  title = {Viterbi algorithm},
  howpublished = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm},
  note = {ultimo accesso 30/06/2021}
}
```

And this is some example of text when I use \cite{}

```
\chapter{Introduzione}

Il Riconoscimento Vocale noto come Automatic Speech Recognition o ASR è il
processo mediante il quale il linguaggio orale umano viene riconosciuto e
successivamente elaborato attraverso un computer o più specificatamente
attraverso un apposito sistema di riconoscimento vocale \cite{intro_asr}.
La parola è il metodo primario di comunicazione tra le persone, tuttavia
le attuali modalità di comunicazione uomo-macchina sono più orientate a
convivere con i limiti dei dispositivi di input/output del computer.
```

but I have this error:

> You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.

And overleaf give me this alert citation 'deepSpeech' on page X undefined on input line X

What should I do?

Comment: unrelated but there is no `epsfig` documentclass option and you should not use the epsfig package unless you need to emulate the syntax used in the 1980s LaTeX 2.09 system. also definitely don't use `\usepackage{plain}` at all, it is unrelated to the `plain` bibliography style. (I wrote both `epsfig` and `plain` packages)

Comment: it is hard to debug your error if you show no example. please add a `\cite{deepSpeech}` to your example and check that you get that error after running bibtex, then someone can debug.

Comment: This is a template given from the university, I didn't change anything, are there some packages or some alternatives ways to crate the bibliography using `\cite{}' ?

Comment: the error is most likely in code you have not shown, eg if you have a syntax error in your bib file bibtex will not be able to generate the bibliography, but you have not shown your full bibliograophy and have not shown the log file that bibtex wrote so what can we say to help? Currently your question asks why there is no bibliography and you have posted an example document that has no `\cite` so getting no bibliography is the expected result.  If you want an answer other than "this is the expected result of the document posted" you need to give some clues.

Answer (score 1):

bibtex produces the error

```
$ bibtex aa550
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2021)
The top-level auxiliary file: aa550.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: biblio.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 81 of file biblio.bib
 :   
 :   Institution = {Università di Pisa},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--to sort, need author or key in intro_asr
(There was 1 error message)
```

so can not generate the bibliography

add the comma missing from the line above

`Title = {Speech To Text}` **`,`**

then you just get a warning

```
Warning--to sort, need author or key in intro_asr
```

and a bibliography is built

running latex again then gives the error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 ...tps://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riconoscimento_
                                                  vocale.
```

so you need to use `\url`..

```
  howpublished = {\url{https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riconoscimento_vocale}},
```

[image]

Comment: I did all the things you suggested but got the same error, maybe it's an Overleaf problem, did you compile manually or did you use overleaf?

Comment: I compiled manually but the problem is not overleaf, it is syntax errors in your document. After you have fixed the errors use the overleaf menu to delete cached files so you delete the corrupted bibliography and start from a clean project. @Gabrielenones